# flask app.config.from_pyfile не выдает ошибок, но не читает файл так, как должно вроде бы

Tags: python, flask

файл `app/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_pyfile('app.conf')

    @app.route('/')
    def hi():
         return 'Hello, Flask!'
    return app
```

Файл `app/app.conf`:

```
DEBUG=True
TESTING=True
```

Не работает что-то, все равно Production-конфигурация используется....

```
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

как заставить конфигурационный файл реально читать?

Comment: Во Flask 1.0 всё поменяли, и теперь (свежепоявившееся, кстати) окружение задаётся через переменную окружения `FLASK_ENV` — и **только** через переменную окружения, в конфиг его прописать нельзя (опция `ENV` игнорируется). Подробнее в справке http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/ (но можно записать переменные окружения в dotenv-файл, подробнее об этом тоже в справке)

Comment: @andreymal в какой dotenv-файл? у меня с английским не все хорошо.

Comment: Подтягивайте английский, умение читать документацию — очень полезная вещь

Comment: @andreymal я так понял, можно FLASK_ENV в bashrc прописать. это оно?

Comment: Ну, как вариант

Answer (score 0, accepted):

только с помощью переменной окружения `FLASK_ENV` можно изменить окружение в Flask 1.0. прописал `export FLASK_ENV="development"` в .bashrc и все решил. подробнее - http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/